# How to make objects bounce off each other in canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I was trying to make the balls in my program bouncing from each other, but it didn't work and most of the time it just get glitched.
**Here is the source code of my main:**

```
from tkinter import *
from Ball import *
import time
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 500
window = Tk()


canvas = Canvas(window,height=HEIGHT,width = WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
basket_ball = Ball(canvas,0,0,100,1,1,"orange")
soccer_ball = Ball(canvas,399,399,499,1,1,"black")

while True:
    basket_ball_coords = canvas.coords(basket_ball.image)
    soccer_ball_coords = canvas.coords(soccer_ball.image)
    basket_ball.move()
    soccer_ball.move()
    print (basket_ball_coords)
    print (soccer_ball_coords)
    if basket_ball_coords[2] == soccer_ball_coords[0] and ((soccer_ball_coords[3] - basket_ball_coords[3])<= 100 and (soccer_ball_coords[3] - basket_ball_coords[3])> -101):
        basket_ball.xVelo = -basket_ball.xVelo
        soccer_ball.xVelo = -soccer_ball.xVelo
    if basket_ball_coords[3] == soccer_ball_coords[1] and ((soccer_ball_coords[2]- basket_ball_coords[2]<=100)and (soccer_ball_coords[2] - basket_ball_coords[2])> -101):
        basket_ball.yVelo = -basket_ball.yVelo
        soccer_ball.yVelo = -soccer_ball.yVelo
    if basket_ball_coords[0] == soccer_ball_coords[2] and ((soccer_ball_coords[3] - basket_ball_coords[3]) <= 100 and (soccer_ball_coords[3] - basket_ball_coords[3]) > -101):
        basket_ball.xVelo = -basket_ball.xVelo
        soccer_ball.xVelo = -soccer_ball.xVelo
    if basket_ball_coords[1] == soccer_ball_coords[3] and ((soccer_ball_coords[2]- basket_ball_coords[2]<=100)and (soccer_ball_coords[2] - basket_ball_coords[2])> -101):
        basket_ball.yVelo = -basket_ball.yVelo
        soccer_ball.yVelo = -soccer_ball.yVelo
    window.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)


window.mainloop()
```

**Here is the Ball class I used to create Ball objects**

```
class Ball:
    def __init__ (self,canvas,x,y,diameter,xVelo,yVelo,color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.image = canvas.create_oval(x,y,diameter,diameter,fill=color)
        self.xVelo = xVelo
        self.yVelo = yVelo
    def move(self):
        coordinates = self.canvas.coords(self.image)
        if (coordinates[2] >= self.canvas.winfo_width() or coordinates[0] < 0):
            self.xVelo = -self.xVelo
        if (coordinates[3] >= self.canvas.winfo_height() or coordinates[1] < 0):
            self.yVelo = -self.yVelo
        self.canvas.move(self.image,self.xVelo,self.yVelo)
```

Comment: There is a good "contact" answer already given here. (Though it doesn't give you the bounce angle of the balls).  Also, make sure the balls have cleared each other after the bounce before allowing them to bounce on each other again, for example changing their velocity vectors but not evaluating movement before reevaluating contact.

Answer (score 2):

The balls "bounce" if the distance between the centers of the balls is less than the sum of their radiuses.

The Pythagorean theorem says the Distance is the square root of the sum of the squares of the x and y deltas.

Assuming:

- x and y passed are upper left corner (?)
- self.radius = diameter/2
- self.center_x = x + self.radius
- self.center_y = y + self.radius

add to Class Ball:

```
def intersects_ball(self, other):
    xdelta = self.center_x - other.center_x
    ydelta = self.center_y - other.center_y
    distance = math.sqrt(xdelta*xdelta + ydelta*ydelta)
    return distance < (self.radius + other.radius)
```

Edited to add:

What happens to the balls when they collide depends on each ball's
velocity vector and mass, and presumably the offset angle of collision...

Here are a couple of online examples with source that work:

- A Python (and Matplotlib) ball collision simulation

  https://scipython.com/blog/two-dimensional-collisions/
- The wikipedia page on elastic collisions references this page

  https://www.vobarian.com/collisions/index.html

  which includes a short PDF discussing the theory, as well
  as source and binary for a Windows C++ program that simulates ball collision.